# ScrollView makes content disappear

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to put a custom listView into a scrollView and when I scroll down and up I lose the top items in the listView which are a TextView and a CheckBox for some reason.
Here's my code:
activity_program.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_program_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:text="Program name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_program_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="program info, talk abt sets, reps, weight etc..." />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="395dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_savework"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:text="Save Workout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My custom listView contains these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_exercice_title"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cb_exercicedone"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Exercice title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_exercice_title"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_setdone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="7dp"
            android:text="Set" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_set_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_reps"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Reps x" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_reps_number"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_weight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:text="Weight" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_weight_number"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_kgorlbs"
            android:layout_width="59dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="kg/lbs"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_exercicedone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my ListActivity I use a custom adapter to fill the ListView with the above template and only edit the tv_set_number (for now) then set the tv_exercice_title's visibility to "gone" to add more sets.
If you think the problem could be in my java code let me know in the comment and I will post it.
Please tell me what's the problem.
Here's some screenshots:
Before I scroll:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubTRF.jpg)
After I scroll:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M06G.jpg)

Comment: Putting a ListView inside  a ScrollView will cause you different problems (that you can read  about in hundreds of questions here) , as ListView already has scroll and both scrolls conflict with each other. Do you really need to do it? In you XML just delete the scrollview and the linearlayout and leave the listview alone with proper dimensions. It will scroll.

Comment: You're totally right. And I was wondering why there was two scroll bars. I fixed it but the problem's still there.. I scroll down and up and I lose the TextView and the CheckBox. Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on which textviews you lose? a screenshot would be cool. I assume the template is the item template that you use as getView(). also why do you set the tv_exercise_title to "gone"? Mind that you have other layout elements dependent on it, and when you assign a visiblity to "gone", the layout processor skips the element. I bet this is very related to your problem. If you need this textview to be kind of a header, take a look at ListView.addHeaderView.

Comment: I'll explain the whole thing, I have three kinds of programs: Beginner, Medium and Professional. I want each one of them to have its own list of exercises, so when you choose a program you go to a ListActivity with all the exercises. Each exercise contains a title with a checkbox and a list of sets. I never tried addHeaderView but looks like I'm going to have to let go of the checkbox, right?

Comment: I added screen shots!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are using the `ListView` to generate different kinds of rows and you're missing some steps. You could also consider to rethink the structure, as maybe this would better fit into a `ExpandableListView`: from the screenshots you post seems like you'd have a set of rows that hierarchically belong to a `group` view.

The `ExpandableListView` would fit this purpose, and also allow to collapse/expand the groups. I'd take a look at it, it's really easy, you'd only have to make the adapter descend from `ExpandableListViewAdapter` and provide methods to obtain the Group views (Your title & checkbox) and the item views (the sets with reps, weight, etc...)

If, on the contrary, you want to make it with a ListView, there are some issues to care about (I'll call **TITLE ROWS** to those with the title & checkbox, and **regular rows** to the regular ones)

What is happening now is, when you create a `view`  and this view is not a **TITLE ROW**, you are setting the visibility of the title to `GONE`. But if you scroll, ie., DOWN and a TITLE row has to appear from the upper edge, the View you are given to recycle is the one that just left the screen by the lower edge, that was probably a REGULAR ROW. So in getView() you not only have to set Visibility to GONE for regular rows, but also back to VISIBLE for Title Rows. Google an explanation on how View recycling works for ListView and you'll understand it right away.

`ListView` provides a mechanism to help in these cases: The View Types:

- You declare 2 "row types" overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)` in your adapter. Type 0 will be TITLE ROWS, and Type 1 would be REGULAR ROWS.
- In `getView` / `convertView` you'll generate / reuse the 2 different views separately based on the type.

.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
     return 2; // you have 2 different types
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     if (position IS A TITLE ROW) return 0; else return 1;
}
```

... and then in `getView()` {

```
if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {

      // it's a TITLE ROW, create / reuse it accordingly

} else {

      // it's a REGULAR ROW, create / reuse it accordingly
}
```

This has the advantage that `ListView` does some of the dirty work for you, so you'll be given the correct view type to recycle.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, man. I'm currently trying to make it work using the second pattern. I can't thank you enough, thank you.

Comment: Actually, the way to thank in this forum is called **accepting the answer** by clicking on the checkmark. Take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and good luck with your ListView!